# Cocos2D Score Counter will not count score

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, counter

I making a game in Cocos2D. I made a score counter on my screen, and when I hit an enemy it adds a point to the score. When I run it, and when I hit an enemy the project terminates.

It is probably because of this: Format specifies type 'id' but the argument has type 'int', referring to this line of code:

```
- (void)addPoint
{
 score = score + 1; // score++; will also work.
 [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", score]];
}
```

It says it wants me to replace the @"%@" to @"%d", because that will not make the score work, please help me fix this.

Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong with what the compiler tells you to do ? simply do it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, replace %@ with %d. Score is integer, your question itself has answer..why simply asked here?

```
 [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score]];
```